# Sending object in ajax get-method Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-rest

I am trying to recieve an User-object from the database using this rest-method:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/users")
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public Collection<User> getAllUsers(@RequestBody(required = false) User user) throws BadHttpRequest {
        System.out.println(user);//ALWAYS RETURNING NULL :(
        if (user == null) {
            return service.getAllUsers(); //Always returns this!
        } else if (user.getUserId() == null) {
            return Collections.singletonList(service.getUserByEmail(user.getUsername()));//I  want this
        } else if(user.getUsername() == null){
            return Collections.singletonList(service.getUserById(user.getUserId()));
        }else{
            throw new BadHttpRequest(new Exception("User id/email mismatch"));
        }
    }
```

I use this javascript:

```
var user = [{ "username": "fms7@hotmail.no", "userId": 1}];

$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/rest/users/",
    data: JSON.stringify({ User: user }),
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
    error: function(errMsg) {
        alert("bais");
    }
});
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is creating problem.

```
data: JSON.stringify({ User: user })
```

You should change it to:

```
data: { User:JSON.stringify(user) }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It didnt help. Thanks for trying!

Comment: what is the error now? Try providing:
contentType: "application/json",

I did the same thing and it seemed to work in my project.
 $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'JsonServlet',
 dataType: 'Json',
 Json: 'Json',
 data: {send: JSON.stringify(objc), name:namess, formid:valu},
 error: function(data) {alert("There was a problem in saving the form"); },
 success:function(data) { alert("Form saved and successfully updated to database"); }

 });